# helm not able to list releases in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am using AKS version 1.14.8 with helm version 2.14.0 and tiller version v2.15.2. RBAC is disabled on the cluster.

Any hints on why this error is happening?

> helm list --tiller-namespace dev1 --debug
>    ✔  11288  17:06:25 [debug] Created tunnel using local port:
>   '54671'
>
> [debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:54671"
>
> Error: an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from
>   succeeding (get configmaps)

tiller rolebinding:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-binding
  namespace: dev1
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: dev1
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: tiller-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

tiller roles:

```
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager
  namespace: dev1
rules:
- apiGroups: [ "", "batch", "extensions", "apps", "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

tiller service account:

```
---
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: dev1
```

Answer (score 0):

if rbac is disabled you dont need roles for tiller to work. so you have to install it without `--service-account`

not sure why would you create a kubernetes clusters without RBAC, though

Comment: i now enabled rbac, and still same issue